# Unregister-Event not removing orphaned event subscriptions

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm using this to subscribe to shutdown events for a particular computer:

```
Register-WMIEvent -ComputerName MyServer1 -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerShutdownEvent” -SourceIdentifier "ShutdownWatcher" -Action { 
    Write-Host "MyServer1 has been shutdown"
}
```

This works find and I receive the shutdown text when the computer is shut down.

The problem is that once the event has fired if I try to use the following to remove the event subscription nothing happens and the subscription remains.

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "ShutdownWatcher"
```

It's as though the event subscription is orphaned and now can't be removed. It's orphaned and completely useless as it doesn't fire when another shutdown is performed. I'd like to remove the subscription once it has fired.

Anyone know how to remove orphaned event subscriptions ? One way is to shutdown the Powershell session but I don't really want to do that.

Comment: When you say it remains - it shows up when executing get-eventsubscriber?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to clear out all subscriptions with:

```
Get-EventSubscriber -Force | Unregister-Event -Force
```

Comment: I did try the -Force option for Unregister-Event. That didn't clear out the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a timer.  I had somehow left a timer with the same SourceIdentifier name in my PowerShell session.  Whenever I would wait for my 10 second timer, it would always return immediately.

I saved the output of the Wait-Event and could access the EventIdentifier, which allowed me to Remove-Event by the EventIdentifier. If I used the SourceIdentifier, I could not access the orphaned event.  I could tell it was orphaned by examining the output of my Wait-Event.TimeGenerated, which was old. You will need to be able to access the orphaned event by the EventIdentifier which is unique.

```
$eventDone = "Done"
$job2 = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer2 -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier $eventDone

$timer2.Interval = 10000;
$timer2.AutoReset = $false;
$timer2.Enabled = $true;

$waitEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier $eventDone;
# Look at the $waitEvent.TimeGenerated for a clue it is old
# use the $waitEvent.EventIdentifier to access the event and remove it
$orphanEventID = $waitEvent.EventIdentifier
Remove-Event -EventIdentifier $orphanEventID
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I was able unregister the event subscription by finding the the specific subscriber, and then unregistering it:

```
Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "ShutdownWatcher" | Unregister-Event
```

This is similar to Mathias' answer, however this method targets the specific event subscription.