# PowerShell: how to unregister orphaned WMI events

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query

The following block of code will generate 100 WMI event subscriptions. This particular case is just an example, and will write a string to a file (100 times) whenever a keyboard is plugged in:

```
$KeyboardQuery = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Keyboard'"
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 100; $i++) {
    Register-WmiEvent -Query $KeyboardQuery -Action {
        "A keyboard was just inserted." >> ~\event-log.txt
    }
}
```

When this is executed in PowerShell, the process `WmiPrvSE.exe` consumes 30%-40% of the CPU. If the following is then executed, the event subscriptions are removed and `WmiPrvSE.exe` drops to a normal level of CPU usage or closes altogether:

```
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
```

This all works as expected. However, if the PowerShell window is closed before running `Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event`, `WmiPrvSE.exe` does not exit, and continues to consume 30%-40% of the CPU. When a keyboard is inserted, the string is no longer written to the file. If a new PowerShell window is opened, `Get-EventSubscriber` or `Get-EventSubscriber -Force` cannot find the event subscribers. If all instances of `WmiPrvSE.exe` are forcefully closed, they start again and continue to consume 30%-40% of the CPU. **Even after logging out and back in, `WmiPrvSE.exe` continues to consume the CPU.** The only way I have found to end these event subscriptions is to restart the computer.

How can I end the event subscriptions which were started in a previous PowerShell session?

### Update

---

I discovered that the CPU usage by orphaned event subscriptions can be ended by triggering the event they're subscribed to, even though they do not seem to run the code in the action block after the PowerShell window has been closed. So in this case, plugging in a keyboard after closing PowerShell causes `WmiPrvSE.exe` to return to its normal behavior. It's like the event subscriptions are waiting for the event to be triggered one last time before they can be cleaned up, but are now owned by the WMI system itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential duplicate of this Q&A.

[Unregister-Event not removing orphaned event subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431352/unregister-event-not-removing-orphaned-event-subscriptions)

Quote from the post:

> I had the same problem with a timer. I had somehow left a timer with
>   the same SourceIdentifier name in my PowerShell session. Whenever I
>   would wait for my 10 second timer, it would always return immediately.
>
> I saved the output of the Wait-Event and could access the
>   EventIdentifier, which allowed me to Remove-Event by the
>   EventIdentifier. If I used the SourceIdentifier, I could not access
>   the orphaned event. I could tell it was orphaned by examining the
>   output of my Wait-Event.TimeGenerated, which was old. You will need to
>   be able to access the orphaned event by the EventIdentifier which is
>   unique.

Code from the post:

```
$eventDone = "Done"
$job2 = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer2 -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier $eventDone

$timer2.Interval = 10000;
$timer2.AutoReset = $false;
$timer2.Enabled = $true;

$waitEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier $eventDone;
# Look at the $waitEvent.TimeGenerated for a clue it is old
# use the $waitEvent.EventIdentifier to access the event and remove it
$orphanEventID = $waitEvent.EventIdentifier
Remove-Event -EventIdentifier $orphanEventID
```

Comment: This sounds promising, but when I use `Register-WmiEvent` the returned object doesn't have an `EventId`, it has a `SubscriptionId` instead. The `SubscriptionId` starts at 1, and is only unique to that PowerShell session. If I close PowerShell and open a new window, the new window doesn't have any events with the same IDs from the last window, and throws an exception like the following if I try to look it up anyway: `Get-EventSubscriber : Event subscription with identifier '1' does not exist.`